# angular 7: Server Side Pagination Using Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular 7 and Angular Material as server-side pagination. I got problem with this matter. The problem is the pagination become like this.

[image]

I want to change pagination to become like this 
[image]

How to change it. Example code like bellow:-

**html**

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <div class="example-loading-shade"
       *ngIf="isLoadingResults || isRateLimitReached">
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoadingResults"></mat-spinner>
    <div class="example-rate-limit-reached" *ngIf="isRateLimitReached">
      GitHub's API rate limit has been reached. It will be reset in one minute.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="example-table-container">

    <table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="example-table"
           matSort matSortActive="created" matSortDisableClear matSortDirection="desc">
      <!-- Number Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="number">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>#</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.number}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Title Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Title</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.title}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- State Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="state">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>State</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.state}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Created Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="created">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header disableClear>
          Created
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.created_at | date}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <mat-paginator [length]="resultsLength" [pageSize]="30"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

**Component ts**

```
export class TableHttpExample implements AfterViewInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['created', 'state', 'number', 'title'];
  exampleDatabase: ExampleHttpDatabase | null;
  // data: GithubIssue[] = [];

  resultsLength = 0;
  isLoadingResults = true;
  isRateLimitReached = false;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.exampleDatabase = new ExampleHttpDatabase(this._httpClient);

    // If the user changes the sort order, reset back to the first page.
    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0);

    merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
      .pipe(
        startWith({}),
        switchMap(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = true;
          return this.exampleDatabase!.getRepoIssues(
            this.sort.active, this.sort.direction, this.paginator.pageIndex);
        }),
        map(data => {
          // Flip flag to show that loading has finished.
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          this.isRateLimitReached = false;
          this.resultsLength = data.total_count;

          return data.items;
        }),
        catchError(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          // Catch if the GitHub API has reached its rate limit. Return empty data.
          this.isRateLimitReached = true;
          return observableOf([]);
        })
      ).subscribe(data => this.data = data);
  }
}
```

**Service ts**

```
export interface GithubApi {
  items: GithubIssue[];
  total_count: number;
}

export interface GithubIssue {
  created_at: string;
  number: string;
  state: string;
  title: string;
}
export class ExampleHttpDatabase {
data: GithubIssue[] = [];



/** An example database that the data source uses to retrieve data for the table. */

  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getRepoIssues(sort: string, order: string, page: number): Observable<GithubApi> {
    const href = 'https://api.github.com/search/issues';
    const requestUrl =
        `${href}?q=repo:angular/components&sort=${sort}&order=${order}&page=${page + 1}`;

    return this._httpClient.get<GithubApi>(requestUrl);
  }
}
```

I've try to change it but it not working. I don't have any idea how to change it. Hope you all can help to solve it.

This is my example [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-pagination-server-side-pagination-hmxfgv) code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-pagination-server-side-pagination-awof75

The main idea is that you have to build your own paginator and not using the Material one. It's pretty simple, just add "fixed" buttons like "First", "Prev", "Next", "Last" and with data information (like `length` and `pageSize`) you can create the list of the pages. The only thing which doesn't work is the `pageSize`, don't know why. I think you will be able to find out why in the real app.

Then handle the page changes with a `BehaviorSubject`. Anyway you can see it all in the example.

Styles and maybe some minor things I leave for you. I think you'd like to limit somehow the amount of the displayed pages as there're lots of them etc.

Comment: @Pohon updated the stackblitz link in the answer with the fix. It was solved similarly as the paginator, just create a `BehaviorSubject` and add changes there